# How can I manage my Javascript libraries in Grunt? Using Bower or NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, bower

I just learn how to use Grunt and I find it awesome; I just have one concern about Javascript libraries, the workflow I learned was to search for each library on the web and then place them in a js/libs folder, then combine ALL the JS files in a single one using Uglify.js but I don't think this is the most practical way to do this. I tried using Bower to manage this but then all the libraries are installed in bower_components so there's no point in having a js/libs workflow in Grunt because I would have to install the libraries using Bower and then import them in my html. Which workflow is the most common to manage this in a project? Can't I use npm to install javascript libraries such as jQuery, underscore or Require.js and use them in my Grunt workflow instead of google them everytime I need them? Can't I use bower to install the libraries in my js/libs folders instead of creating a whole bower_components folders tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a *correct* way to answer this question, this a common workflow involves the following:

Starting with `npm init` (or `yarn init` if that's your thing) and then using `npm install --save jquery` (or any dependency). This will add it to your package.json, which means if you ever cleared your node_modules directory, you could call `npm install` and bring all of your dependencies.

After that, workflows very a lot, and I can't answer that for you. However, I will add that npm 4 introduces improved search so you can actually search for the correct module within npm. http://www.npms.io is also a useful site for searching, and the npm site itself is also a reliable option.

All the stuff about bundling and build tools is opinion so don't feel that there is one *right* way to do it. However, you do mention importing them into your hmtl. You can actually use a tool like webpack to bundle all of your javascript into a single bundle file and then just loading that from your html instead of jquery, requireJS, etc.

Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

`Grunt` is just a task runner. `npm` and `bower` and actual package managers.

`npm` - typically used to manage node packages and dependencies.

`bower` - typically used to manage frontend packages and dependencies.

How this fits in with a typical workflow is you'd manage dependencies via one of the aforementioned package managers and then get `grunt` to minify and build your final application.